# Can I use flex-direction to print elements horizontally in the same manner as floats?

Tags: html, css, css-float, flexbox

Forgive the title. I have a list that looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to alphabetize it, so that Character is where Injury: Eye is, Food is where times_hunted is, and Hungry would be where Character is. Of course, CSS floats/flows like rows. I had the hope that I could use `flex-direction: column;` to have CSS understand that "floating left" meant that *x* items would be placed at the top and instead of a max-width on the container, I would just use max-height and I'd be on my merry way. Not quite.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5kkLwgat/1/

Is there any way I can "print CSS out" vertically? I'm trying to avoid using PHP to solve this, as it would be fairly trivial but not the best solution.

```css
.megitsune {
  float: left; 

  display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap;

  width: 1320px; font-size: 11px; margin-bottom: 18px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 .holder {
  width: 160px; cursor: default; position: relative; margin: 0px 16px 4px 0px; border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 2px 5px; font-size: 12px;
 }
  
  .objchange {
  width: 26px;
  padding-left: 2px !important;
  position: absolute; top: -1px; right: -1px; 
  height: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="megitsune">
 <h2 title="Equippable item names are highlighted in blue.">Items</h2>
 <div class="holder" title="Original value: 1" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Bow <input type="text" value="1" data-obj="5" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 1">
    Character <input type="text" value="1" data-obj="2" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    Food <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="7" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 3" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Hungry <input type="text" value="3" data-obj="22" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Injury: Back <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="19" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Injury: Broken Arm <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="16" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Injury: Broken Leg <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="17" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Injury: Eye <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="18" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Iron Axe <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="4" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Iron Sword <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="3" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 5">
    Meat <input type="text" value="5" data-obj="9" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 2">
    temp <input type="text" value="2" data-obj="10" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    temp2 <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="21" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 8">
    times_gathered <input type="text" value="8" data-obj="15" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    times_hunted <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="14" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    time_day <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="11" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    time_night <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="12" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    Wet Wood <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="8" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 1">
    Wood <input type="text" value="1" data-obj="6" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    z_youwin <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="20" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `flex-direction: column` you can make the layout work.

Keep in mind that you will need to define a height on the container.

Without the height limit, the flex items have no reason to wrap.

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5kkLwgat/2/)

Comment: *smacks forehead* The fixed height! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a column flex container with forced line breaks, e.g. each three items:

```css
.holder:nth-of-type(3n) {
  break-after: always;
}
```

Note it's not widely supported yet, only works on Firefox with the old `page-break-after` alias.

```css
.megitsune {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1320px;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.holder {
  width: 160px;
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 16px 4px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.holder:nth-of-type(3n) {
  page-break-after: always;
  break-after: always;
}
.objchange {
  width: 26px;
  padding-left: 2px !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="megitsune">
  <h2 title="Equippable item names are highlighted in blue.">Items</h2>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 1" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Bow <input type="text" value="1" data-obj="5" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 1">
    Character <input type="text" value="1" data-obj="2" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    Food <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="7" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 3" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Hungry <input type="text" value="3" data-obj="22" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Injury: Back <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="19" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Injury: Broken Arm <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="16" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Injury: Broken Leg <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="17" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Injury: Eye <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="18" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Iron Axe <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="4" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Iron Sword <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="3" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 5">
    Meat <input type="text" value="5" data-obj="9" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 2">
    temp <input type="text" value="2" data-obj="10" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    temp2 <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="21" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 8">
    times_gathered <input type="text" value="8" data-obj="15" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    times_hunted <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="14" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    time_day <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="11" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    time_night <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="12" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    Wet Wood <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="8" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 1">
    Wood <input type="text" value="1" data-obj="6" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    z_youwin <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="20" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want columns, use [CSS columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts).

Set the container:

```
.megitsune {
  width: 1320px;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  column-count: 5;
}
```

Set the items:

```
.holder {
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 16px 4px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```css
.megitsune {
  width: 1320px;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  column-count: 5;
}
.holder {
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 16px 4px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
.objchange {
  width: 26px;
  padding-left: 2px !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h2 title="Equippable item names are highlighted in blue.">Items</h2>

<div class="megitsune">
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 1" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Bow
    <input type="text" value="1" data-obj="5" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 1">
    Character
    <input type="text" value="1" data-obj="2" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    Food
    <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="7" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 3" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Hungry
    <input type="text" value="3" data-obj="22" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Injury: Back
    <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="19" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Injury: Broken Arm
    <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="16" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Injury: Broken Leg
    <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="17" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Injury: Eye
    <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="18" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Iron Axe
    <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="4" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0" style="background: #DFEDF7">
    Iron Sword
    <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="3" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 5">
    Meat
    <input type="text" value="5" data-obj="9" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 2">
    temp
    <input type="text" value="2" data-obj="10" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    temp2
    <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="21" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 8">
    times_gathered
    <input type="text" value="8" data-obj="15" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    times_hunted
    <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="14" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    time_day
    <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="11" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    time_night
    <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="12" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    Wet Wood
    <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="8" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 1">
    Wood
    <input type="text" value="1" data-obj="6" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
  <div class="holder" title="Original value: 0">
    z_youwin
    <input type="text" value="0" data-obj="20" data-type="item" class="objchange">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that `columns` still has very limited browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=column